# Knockout and JQueryMobile binding error with templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

With Asp.net MVC, I have two views:

First view:

```
<div data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="subcategorieslistview">
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'subcategory-template', foreach: subcategories }" id="subcategories">
    <script type="text/html" id="subcategory-template">
     <li data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">
       <a data-bind="attr : { title : name, categoryid : categoryId, lazyloaddescriptor : lazyLoadDescriptor}"><label data-bind="text: name"></label></a>
     </li>
   </script>        
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).one("pageinit", function () {
      <!-- Ajax load of view model --->
</script>
```

Second view:

```
<div data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="archivecontainerslistview">
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'archivecontainers-template', foreach: archivecontainers }" id="archivecontainers">
    <script type="text/html" id="archivecontainers-template">
        <li data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: synopsis" class="ui-li-count"></span>
        </li>
    </script>        
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).one("pageinit", function () {
      <!-- Ajax load of view model --->
</script>
```

When I go to the first view, the templating works fine.
I then move to the second view and the templating once again is working as expected.

However, when I hit the back button to go back to the first view, I get an error in knockout.js:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: synopsis is not defined;
```

The field *synopsis* is on the second view and by examining the DOM I see both pages loaded where as I expected the second page to be removed from the DOM (not sure if the error is preventing the second page from being removed from the DOM).

It seems that because the second page is in the DOM when the first page is activated the binding seems to be kicked off in the second page even though the second page is not shown. Not sure if this is correct.

Is there anything in Jquery mobile or KnockOut to somehow remove the binding from the second page so that I can avoid this error?

Comment: Well the bindings shouldn't be applied if `archivecontainers` was empty. Is it empty?

Comment: ArchiveContainers is on the second view as I go "back" to the first view. So I assume it will still have data. So how do I empty it on going back to the first view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unbind view model from view in knockout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032129/unbind-view-model-from-view-in-knockout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything in Jquery mobile or KnockOut to somehow remove the binding from the second page so that I can avoid this error?

Yes.

Have you tried calling [Knockout's `cleanNode()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033428/109941) to remove the binding from the second page?